# ubuntu server, virtualbox, vagrant

Tags: ubuntu, bash

I am trying to change the network adapters for the three vms I am creating to a bridged network. I have a headless ubuntu server 16 and am very novice with bash.

I entered this command, but to no avail (im doing this without a ton of experience):

```
VBoxManage modifyvm vms_acs_1519949237140_4187 --nic bridged --nictype1 QCA61x4A –bridgeadapter1 eth0
```

Am I even close?